# Can not get jQuerys .on to work with dynamical elements even though it's delegated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a static element, but even though i use that, .on do not bind to the dynamic selector.

this is a more simple version than the one i'm working on, but do have the same problem.

The divs are created when i click on the static element, but clicking on the dynamic elements do nothing.

Hope someone here can help me.

HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var test = $('#test');

  test.click(function() {

    var html = document.createElement('div');
    html.className = 'temp';
    $('body').append(html);
    console.log('clicked.');

  });

  test.on('click', '.temp', function() {

    console.log('Temp div removed.');
    $(this).remove();

  });

});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.temp {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the event delegation to the parent of the dynamic elements. You've bounded the event to the `#test` element, but the `.temp` divs are children of the body. You can add the event to the body, or to a dedicated container for the added nodes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var test = $('#test');
  var target = $('#target');

  test.click(function() {

    var html = document.createElement('div');
    html.className = 'temp';
    target.append(html);
    console.log('clicked.');

  });

  target.on('click', '.temp', function() {

    console.log('Temp div removed.');
    $(this).remove();

  });

});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.temp {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)